# Make division by zero equal to zero in a list

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero

I have a list `L` and I want to compute for each element`const/L_j` and get a new list `M` with elements `M_j = const/L_j`. However, there are `L_j` elements that are zero. In this case it is preferred to assign such division to zero. I have made this the script below but it is slow.

```
temp = np.zeros((self.n_features, 1))
for t in range(self.n_features):
    if y[t]!=0:
        temp[t] = x/y[t]
```

My question is similar to this but I want to apply it in a list. Is these a faster way to compute list `M`.

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a computationally faster way to compute this list. You are doing at most one access to compute each element, and you can't do less.

Comment: @NiVeR: The purpose of NumPy is to speed up exactly such computations through vectorization; doing so in this case is orders of magnitude faster than the naive loop solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your array is called `L`, you could do something like

```
M = x/L
M[np.isinf(M)] = 0
```

The additional time required to zero out the bad elements is negligible, even when the number of infinites is large:

```
In [20]: L = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100000)

In [21]: %timeit [0 if l == 0 else 10/l for l in L]
34.9 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [23]: %timeit M = 10/L
263 µs ± 11.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit M[np.isinf(M)] = 0
983 ns ± 40.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another way with time complexity of `O(N)`, iterate over the elements:

```
M = [0 if l == 0 else constant/l for l in L]
```

Comment: Complexity is mostly irrelevant here; a vectorized solution will also be linear time but with a constant that's orders of magnitude smaller.

Comment: @fuglede you are totally right, the point is that it can be done by just 1 iteration over data (coefficient free).

Answer (score 0):

```
def transform_to_M(const, x):
    if x==0:
       return 0
    return const/x

np.fromiter((transform_to_M(const, i) for i in y), float, count=len(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `math.inf`.

```
from math import inf

lst = [2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
const = 1

res = [const / (l or inf) for l in lst]

print(res) # [0.5, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest, easiest and most pythonic way to do this is array masking:

```
M = x / L
M[L == 0] = 0
```

This is one function evaluation faster than fuglede's code.